# to_sql() method of pandas sends primary key column as NULL even if the column is not present in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to insert a data frame into the ***Snowflake*** database table. The database has columns like `id` which is a `primary_key` and `event_id` which is an `integer` field and it's also `nullable`.

I have created a `declarative_base()` class using ***SQLAlchemy*** as shown below -

```
class AccountUsageLoginHistory(Base):

    __tablename__ = constants.TABLE_ACCOUNT_USAGE_LOGIN_HISTORY
    __table_args__ = {
        'extend_existing':True,
        'schema' : os.environ.get('SCHEMA_NAME_AUDITS')
    }

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('id_account_usage_login_history'), primary_key=True)
    event_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
```

The class stated above creates a table in the ***Snowflake*** database.

I have a data frame that has just one column `event_id`.

When I try to insert the data using pandas `to_sql()` method Snowflake returns me an error shown below -

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 100072 (22000): 01991f2c-0be5-c903-0000-d5e5000c6cee: NULL result in a non-nullable column
```

This error is generated by snowflake because `to_sql()` is appending a column `id` and the values are set to `null` for each row of that column.

```
dataframe.to_sql(table_name, self.engine, index=False, method=pd_writer, if_exists="append")
```

***Consider this as case 1 -***

I tried to run an insert query directly to snowflake -

```
insert into "SFOPT_TEST"."AUDITS"."ACCOUNT_USAGE_LOGIN_HISTORY" (ID, EVENT_ID) values(NULL, 33)
```

The query above returned me the same error -

```
NULL result in a non-nullable column
```

The query stated above is how probably the `to_sql()` method might be doing.

***Consider this as case 2 -***

I also tried to insert a row by executing the query stated below -

```
insert into "SFOPT_TEST"."AUDITS"."ACCOUNT_USAGE_LOGIN_HISTORY" (EVENT_ID) values(33)
```

Now, this particular query has been executed successfully by inserting the data into the table and it has also auto-generated value for column `id`.

How can I make `to_sql()` method of pandas to use ***case 2***?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to insert data into Snowflake database table using pandas to\_sql() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230110/unable-to-insert-data-into-snowflake-database-table-using-pandas-to-sql-method)

Comment: no, it does not

Comment: I think it might.  That post mentions making the field nullable in the table in Snowflake, which should make the `to_sql()` command work correctly.  Does it not work?  It will make you CASE 1 above work, but will cause you to want to avoid using CASE 2 manually, which is what the answer states.

Comment: It is inserting `null` for column `id`. I want it to auto increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()` has by default parameter `index=True` which means that it will add an extra column (df.index) when inserting the data.

Some Databases like PostgreSQL have a data type `serial` which allows you to sequentially fill the column with incremental numbers.

Snowflake DB doesn't have that concept but instead, there are other ways to handle it:

**First Option:**
You can use `CREATE SEQUENCE` statement and create a sequence directly in the db - [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-sequence.html) is the official documentation on this topic. The downside of this approach is that you would need to convert your DataFrame into a proper SQL statement:

db preparation part:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE schema.my_sequence START = 1 INCREMENT = 1;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE schema.my_table (i bigint, b text);
```

You would need to convert the DataFrame into Snowflake's `INSERT` statement and use `schema.my_sequence.nextval` to get the next ID value

```
INSERT INTO schema.my_table VALUES
(schema.my_sequence.nextval, 'string_1'),
(schema.my_sequence.nextval, 'string_2');
```

The result will be:

```
i b
1 string_1
2 string_2
```

Please note that there are some [limitations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences.html) to this approach and you need to ensure that each insert statement you do this way will be successful as calling `schema.my_sequence.nextval` and not inserting it will mean that there will be gaps numbers.
To avoid it you can have a separate script that checks if the current insert was successful and if not it will recreate the sequence by calling:

```
REPLACE SEQUENCE schema.my_sequence start = (SELECT max(i) FROM schema.my_table) increment = 1;
```

**Alternative Option:**
You would need to create an extra function that runs the SQL to get the last i you inserted previously.

```
SELECT max(i) AS max_i FROM schema.my_table;
```

and then update the `index` in your DataFrame before running `to_sql()`

```
df.index = range(max_i+1, len(df)+max_i+1)
```

This will ensure that your DataFrame index continues i in your table.
Once that is done you can use

```
df.to_sql(index_label='i', name='my_table', con=connection_object)
```

It will use your index as one of the columns you insert allowing you to maintain the unique index in the table.